# Resize imageview in its frame

Tags: ios, imageview, autolayout

I am trying to create a view that has 4 children

1 imageview
3 labels

The ImageView is supposed to take up the entire frame, and it doesnt

I've added layout constraints to it so that it would adjust to the sides.
However, i am initiating the view with different frames, and the image view size doesnt change

How do i make the image take up the entire purple area, of which it is a subview?

This is my xib file:

[image]

and this is how it looks on the device screen
the purple view is the frame i allocated for the given view:
and the green view is the entire screen

[image]

my init code:

```
NSArray *topViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"BagView" owner:self options:nil];
[self addSubview:topViews[0]];
[self.shoppingBag setFrame:self.bounds];
```

Comment: What kind of constraints have you set on the UIImageView? Does the UIImageView have top, trailing(right), bottom, leading(left) constraints and no height or width constraints?

Comment: yes those are exactly the constraints i put, and all the constants are 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *topViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"BagView" owner:self options:nil];

UIView *v = topViews[0];
v.frame = self.bounds;
[self addSubview:v];
```

fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

- Set the `contentMode` property of UIIMageView  to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`

> [your_imageview setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];